# Using Pool.map with a list : TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I m trying to accelerate my code so I use :

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count()-1)
print('Start multi process')
res = pool.map(max_def_in_circle, range(len(dataT)), All_index_in_c)
```

with All_index_in_c is a list of list : here a preview

```
[[2, 12], [11, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [0, 3, 12], [], [21, 22, 44, 45, 46], .... ]
```

and `max_def_in_circle` a very basic function which works fine

But when I run this I got this error message :

```
<ipython-input-18-3bd316855b1c> in <module>
      6 # pool.join()
      7 print('Start multi process')
----> 8 res = pool.map(max_def_in_circle, range(len(dataT)), All_index_in_c)

/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    362         in a list that is returned.
    363         '''
--> 364         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    365 
    366     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in _map_async(self, func, iterable, mapper, chunksize, callback, error_callback)
    483 
    484         task_batches = Pool._get_tasks(func, iterable, chunksize)
--> 485         result = MapResult(self, chunksize, len(iterable), callback,
    486                            error_callback=error_callback)
    487         self._taskqueue.put(

/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in __init__(self, pool, chunksize, length, callback, error_callback)
    795         self._value = [None] * length
    796         self._chunksize = chunksize
--> 797         if chunksize <= 0:
    798             self._number_left = 0
    799             self._event.set()

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

But When I did my search on this problem, several people seem able to use list in pool.map I don't understand why, maybe it is a version problem ?
If someone can help me,
Thanks

Comment: For multiple arguments, you can use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

As @DarrylG mentioned, `pool.map` supports functions of one argument only. Use `pool.starmap` to pass multiple arguments to `max_def_in_circle`, e.g.

```
res = pool.starmap(max_def_in_circle, zip(range(len(dataT)), All_index_in_c))
```

The `zip` function will output the entries in each list as pairs. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple arguments for the function can't be passed in this way. Our third argument is picked up as "chunksize", which needs to be a positive integer and hence the error.

```
pool.map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
```

Comment: How can I know the chunksize ?
And when I invert the args as you do I got this time the error :
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'int'

Comment: okay, so what are the two arguments other than function max_def_in_circle in the pool.map() ? The pool.map needs the function, the iterator(the input on which the function will operate) and chunksize

Comment: The function args are an integer and a list, I need these 2 arguments to run my function. And I need to iterate these 2 arguments, and it works fine with usual map function

Comment: Got it.By what you are passing the third argument is picked up as "chunksize" rather than argument to function and that needs to be a positive int and hence you are getting the error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments  - let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: For multiple arguments, you can use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) rather than map.  Example of usage: [How to use multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments)